# changing values in a vector

Tags: rust

I am looking to have a code review on [this tiny repository](https://github.com/Dmitry-N-Medvedev/algorithms/tree/quick-find).

The code seems to work, but I am not sure if I have written it in idiomatic Rust.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct QuickFind {
    items: Vec<u64>,
}

impl QuickFind {
    pub fn new(length: u64) -> QuickFind {
        let mut result: QuickFind = QuickFind { items: Vec::new() };

        for i in 0..length {
            result.items.push(i);
        }

        result
    }

    pub fn union(&mut self, left_index: u64, right_index: u64) {
        let left_group_id = self.items[left_index as usize];

        self.items[right_index as usize] = left_group_id;
    }

    pub fn get_items(&self) -> &[u64] {
        &self.items
    }

    pub fn is_connected(&self, left_index: u64, right_index: u64) -> bool {
        self.items[left_index as usize] == self.items[right_index as usize]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Collect the iterator into the new vector

You don't need to loop over a range to populate a vector with elements. The `collect` method has enough information to construct a `Vec<u64>` on the spot. This also makes the `result` variable unnecessary.

```
    pub fn new(length: u64) -> QuickFind {
        QuickFind {
            items: (0..length).collect(),
        }
    }
```

#### C-GETTER

The [convention for getter names](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#c-getter) is *without* the prefix `get_`, unless `get` makes up the entire method name. `get_items(&self)` becomes `items(&self)`.

#### Reconsider `usize` as the index type.

There appear to be multiple conversions from `u64` to `usize` in the code. Indeed, `usize` is the common integral type for referring to a relative (non-negative) position of a value in memory. With that done, the only integer cast is in `new`, so as to turn the range (0..length) into a range of values rather than a range of indices.

#### The final code:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b9df5a715adc1d86985f540207df20c)

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct QuickFind {
    items: Vec<u64>,
}

impl QuickFind {
    pub fn new(length: usize) -> QuickFind {
        QuickFind {
            items: (0..length as u64).collect(),
        }
    }

    pub fn union(&mut self, left_index: usize, right_index: usize) {
        let left_group_id = self.items[left_index];

        self.items[right_index] = left_group_id;
    }

    pub fn items(&self) -> &[u64] {
        &self.items
    }

    pub fn is_connected(&self, left_index: usize, right_index: usize) -> bool {
        self.items[left_index] == self.items[right_index]
    }
}
```